# Variables do not work in email form

Tags: database, emails

I made a simple email form to send an attachment (image). All sender information is taken from the joomla database, the user selects from the dropdown list (populated from database) new name of image.

- In lines 1-50, I created all the variables from the joomala base
- In lines 50-56 I have tested variables with echo and everything works
- In email form after line 58 variables $alias and $sender does not work (get  empty space instead of value in email message)

  ```
  <?php
  // $link_id
  $link_id = JRequest::getInt('link_id');

  // $sender
  $db = JFactory::getDbo();
  $query1 = $db->getQuery(true);
  $query1->select('link_name');
  $query1->from($db->quoteName('#__hikers'));
  $query1->where($db->quoteName('#__hikers.link_id')." = ".$db->quote($link_id));
  $db->setQuery($query1);
  $sender = $db->loadResult();

  // $alias
  $db = JFactory::getDbo();
  $querya = $db->getQuery(true);
  $querya->select('#__hikers.alias');
  $querya->from($db->quoteName('#__hikers'));
  $querya->where($db->quoteName('#__hikers.link_id')." = ".$db->quote($link_id));
  $db->setQuery($querya);
  $alias = $db->loadResult();

  // $sender_email
  $db = JFactory::getDbo();
  $query3 = $db->getQuery(true);
  $query3->select('#__users.email');
  $query3->from($db->quoteName('#__users'));
  $query3->where($db->quoteName('#__users.id')." = ".$db->quote($userId));
  $db->setQuery($query3);
  $sender_email = $db->loadResult();

  // Dropdown menu from database

  $db = JFactory::getDbo();
  $squery = $db->getQuery(true);
  $squery->select('peak_name');
  $squery->from($db->qn('#__unclimbedpeaks'));
  $squery->where($db->quoteName('#__unclimbedpeaks.link_id')." = ".$db->quote($link_id));
  $squery->order('peak_id ASC');
  $db->setQuery($squery);
  $speaks_list = $db->loadColumn();
  $speaks_select  = '<select name="name" id="peaks">';
  $speaks_select .= '<option value="">-- Odaberi vrh --</option>';
  foreach($speaks_list as $p){
  $speaks_select .= '<option value="' . $p . '">' . $p . '</option>';  
      }
  $speaks_select .= '</select>';
  ?>
  <?php

  // Testing $alias, $sender, $sender_email and $link_id

  echo $alias;
  echo $sender;
  echo $sender_email;
  echo $link_id;

  // Email form

  if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
  {   $svrh_name = $_POST['name'];
      $output = header('Location: https://mysite/'.$alias); /* Redirect browser */;
      //Set the form flag to no display (cheap way!)
      $flags = 'style="display:none;"';

      //Deal with the email
      $to = 'admin@MySite.com';
      $subject = 'Message from '.$sender;
      $message = 'This is message with '.$svrh_name.' from '.$sender.'. Please visit link: https://MySite/'.$alias.' Sender email:'.$sender_email.' Sender ID:'.$link_id.'';
      $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])));
      $filename = $svrh_name.'.jpg';
      $boundary =md5(date('r', time())); 
      $headers = 'From: '.$sender_email.' \r\nReply-To: '.$sender_email.'';
      $headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"_1_$boundary\"";
      $message="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

  --_1_$boundary
  Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

  --_2_$boundary
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"
  Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

  $message

  --_2_$boundary--
  --_1_$boundary
  Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$filename\" 
  Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
  Content-Disposition: attachment 

  $attachment
  --_1_$boundary--";

      mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  }
  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>MailFile</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php echo $output; ?>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo         $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" <?php echo $flags;?>>
  <?php echo $speaks_select; ?>
  <p><label for="file">File</label> <input type="file" name="file" id="file"></p>
  <p><input type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2" value="Send"></p>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: `JRequest` is deprecated. Please use [JInput](https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput)

Comment: Thank you. I tried to change it, but it still does not work

Comment: What are you expecting from `$output = header('Location: https://mysite/'.$alias); /* Redirect browser */;` `header()` doesn't offer a return value.  Are you trying to exit the script prematurely and load the new page?

Comment: @When you say `$alias` and `$sender` don't work, is that to mean that the other variables DO contain their expected values?  Have you implemented Lodder's advice to use Joomla's mailing technique?  You should try to reduce your total calls to the database by 1. merging the `$sender` and `$alias` queries and 2. only query for `$speaks_select` when you are building your form.  You should not be using `display:none` as a short cut, you should be using an `if/else` block to isolate pre-submission and post-submission processes.

Comment: When your page is first loaded, do you have a url with `?link_id=[integer]`?  What happens when you submit (`POST`) your form?  Your `$_GET['link_id']` data is lost isn't it?  `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is delivering the script, but not your querystring.  I think you should be retaining the `link_id` during form submission by writing a hidden input field.

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa. This is old post ant it's solved before 6 months

Comment: I know this is an old post, but this is an abandoned page which represents a dead end for future Joomla researchers.  If this site/community is going to be more useful/relevant, we need to look after the current pool of questions and answers.  We all need to care more to generate clearer questions and educational answers.  If you have a solution that uses best practices, please post it as an answer and accept it so that readers can benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Your `where` clauses are incorrect. You don't need to use the table name, only the column

So replace the clauses as shown below:

---

**Query 1:**

```
$query1->where($db->quoteName('#__hikers.link_id')." = ".$db->quote($link_id));
```

with:

```
$query1->where($db->quoteName('link_id')." = ".$db->quote($link_id));
```

---

**Query 2:**

```
$querya->where($db->quoteName('#__hikers.link_id')." = ".$db->quote($link_id));
```

with:

```
$querya->where($db->quoteName('link_id')." = ".$db->quote($link_id));
```

---

**Query 3:**

```
$query3->where($db->quoteName('#__users.id')." = ".$db->quote($userId));
```

with:

```
$query3->where($db->quoteName('id')." = ".$db->quote($userId));
```

---

**Query 4:**

```
$squery->where($db->quoteName('#__unclimbedpeaks.link_id')." = ".$db->quote($link_id));
```

with:

```
$squery->where($db->quoteName('link_id')." = ".$db->quote($link_id));
```

---

Rather than using PHP's native `mail()` function, I suggest you utilise Joomla's mail wrapp which uses PHPMailer, so replace:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Example from here: https://docs.joomla.org/Sending_email_from_extensions

Comment: Thank you, I made these updates, but I have the same result.
Variables work when I test them with echo, but they do not work in email form

Comment: @Midhat - I've updated my answer. Please refer to the Joomla documentation as you should be using Joomla's API for your code.

Comment: Is it possible to send file using Joomla's API ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Please refer to the documentation link I added in my answer

Comment: @Lodder the bulk of your answer is not true.  Explicitly identifying the tablename for each column in the WHERE clauses will not cause trouble (though I'll agree that it is needless for this case).  Please consider trimming/rewording your advice about the queries. There is A LOT to fix with the question.  On Stackoverflow, I'd say this question is Too Broad, Unclear, and/or Why isn't my code working.  JSX has a more forgiving culture, but in its current state this page is going to be mostly useless to future researchers and appear forever abandoned.  How do you suggest we proceed?

Comment: @mickmackusa My answer is only 1 of potential others. The community is of course within their own right to add their own answers based on their own suggestions. What I wrote was purely based on what I could see and think of at the time...just like most of my answers. They'll not always be entirely complete and could of course sometimes be wrong

Comment: I don't think I know enough to make a complete answer here (and of course more details from the OP would be largely helpful).  Shall I post a Wiki answer?  Are you interested in adding to whatever I cook up?  or are you generally not interested?

Comment: Doesn't need to be a wiki. Standard answer will do ;)

Answer (score 0):

I feel that there is quite a bit wrong with your posted code and there are essential details that are not included in the question.  I'll start this Wiki-answer so that anyone can add their expertise and correct the code block with best practices.  The following was not tested.

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$link_id = (int)$jinput->get('link_id', 0, 'int');  // initally $_GET, but later $_POST
$submit = $jinput->post->get('submit2', '', 'string');
$peak = $jinput->post->get('peak', '', 'string');
$files = $jinput->files->get('file', [], 'array');

$db = JFactory::getDbo();  // just one reusable database connection / object

if ($submit != 'Send') {
    // pre-submission:
    try {
        $peaks_query = $db->getQuery(true)
                          ->select('peak_name')
                          ->from('#__unclimbedpeaks')
                          ->where("link_id = $link_id")
                          ->order('peak_id');
        $db->setQuery($peaks_query);
        $peaks_list = $db->loadColumn();
        $peaks_select = '<select name="peak" id="peak">';
        $peaks_select .= '<option value="">-- Odaberi vrh --</option>';
        foreach ($peaks_list as $p) {
            $peaks_select .= '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($p, ENT_QUOTES) . '">' . $p . '</option>';
        }
        $peaks_select .= '</select>';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Syntax Error @ unclimbedpeaks table"; //  , $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>MailFile</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
        <p><label for="peak">Remaining Peaks</label> <?php echo $peaks_select; ?></p>
        <p><label for="file">File</label> <input type="file" name="file" id="file"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2" value="Send"></p>
        <input type="hidden" name="link_id" value="$link_id">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
} else {
    // post-submission
    try {
        $hiker_query = $db->getQuery(true)
                          ->select(array('link_name', 'alias'))
                          ->from('#__hikers')
                          ->where("link_id = $link_id");
        $db->setQuery($hiker_query);
        if (!$hiker = $db->loadAssoc()) {
            echo "Failed to find hiker";
        } else {
            $mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
            $user = JFactory::getUser();
            $sender_email = $user->email;
            $mailer->setSender($sender_email);

            $mailer->addRecipient('admin@mysite.com');
            $mailer->setSubject('Message from ' . $hiker['link_name']);
            $mailer->setBody('This is message with ' . $peak . ' from ' . $hiker['link_name'] . '. Please visit link: https://MySite/' . $hiker['alias'] . ' Sender email:' . $sender_email . ' Sender ID:' . $link_id);
            /*
             * Not sure how to prepare the file attachment portion...
             * $mailer->addAttachment();
             */
            $send = $mailer->Send();
            if ($send === true) {
                echo 'Mail sent';
            } else {
                echo 'Error sending email';
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Syntax Error @ hiker table"; //  , $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```